# Stabilizing an open book with Anosov piece

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemann-surfaces, mapping-class-groups, contact-geometry

It was proven by Colin and Honda in [Stabilizing the monodromy of an open book decomposition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0581.pdf) that any diffeomorphism can be made pseudo-Anosov and right-veering after a series of positive stabilizations.

Also we have the following result by A. Fathi in [Dehn twists and pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphisms](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389156) that says that if $\phi$ is pseudo-Anosov and $\gamma \subset S$ is a simple closed curve, then $t_\gamma^n \circ \phi$ is pseudo-Anosov except for at most seven consecutive values of $n$.

My question relaxes the conditions on $\phi$ and changes "composing with Dehn twists" to "stabilizing". More concretely:

> Let $\tilde\phi:S \to S$ be a diffeomorphism of an oriented compact surface with boundary such that $\phi|_{\partial S} = id$ and such that $\phi$ contains a pseudo-Anosov piece in its Nielsen-Thurson decomposition. Let $c \subset S$ be a properly embedded arc. Attach a $1$-handle to $S$ along $\partial c$ and stabilize $\tilde\phi$ using this handle and the arc $c$. Call $\phi$ the stabilized diffeomorphism.
>   Can we be sure that $\phi$ contains a pseudo-Anosov piece as well?
>   Do there exist any necessary and sufficient conditions on $c$ so that the above is true?

Comment: Here is a possible (?) sufficient condition: that the associated closed three-manifold (the mapping torus of the open book) have a hyperbolic piece in its JSJ decomposition.  Proving this seems delicate, however.

Comment: I think what you suggest is actually equivalent (or very close to it). Since there there is an equivalence between Seifert-periodic pieces and hyperbolic-pseudo-anosov pieces.