# What does it mean for two natural numbers to be *approximately equal*?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, notation, mapping-class-groups, contact-geometry

This is related to this [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333340/on-a-corollary-of-a-paper-by-colin-and-honda) of mine about a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0581.pdf) of Colin and Honda.

I'm trying to follow the proofs line by line. I found the following piece of notation that is not explained in the text so i ask for its meaning or a reference where it is used other than this. I quote the beginning of page 6 in the cited paper

> Since $d(h(\gamma_0), \gamma_0) = N$, it follows that $d(h(\alpha), h(\gamma_0)) \approx N$ for every $\alpha$. (Here $\approx$ means *approximately equal to*.)

For some context: $\gamma_0, \alpha$ are simple closed curves in a surface, $h$ is an automorphism of the surface, $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the distance in the complex of curves (which is a natural number) and $N$ is a natural number. Hence, we are saying that two natural numbers are *approximately equal*?

Since $N$ is a number that, in that context, is *arbitrarily large* one could think that it means that $\lim_{N\to \infty} d(h(\gamma_0), \gamma_0) - N = 0$? But later on the text a similar exppresion appears changing $N$ by $0$ (end of page $7$).

So I would appreciate someone explaining to me what it means.

Comment: You didn't say that $d(h(\alpha), h(\gamma_0))$ is a natural number.  Could it be that $d(h(\alpha), h(\gamma_0))$ is a real number, close to $N$ in the sense of distance ${}  < 1/2$ ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that the distance in the complex of curves is a natural number as well. (it is explained in page 3 of the paper)

Comment: Maybe it means the difference is bounded?

Comment: Maybe. I don't think so because of the context. But since it is there and it is unexplained I guess it is "common jargon". So I hope somebody can tell me what it means.

Comment: They just mean that the numbers are a uniformly bounded distance from N.  Here the $\alpha$ are distance one from $\gamma_0$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the last sentence. Also uniformly on what?

Comment: Uniform in $\alpha$, I think. That is, two functions of $\alpha$ are approximately equal if their difference is a bounded function of $\alpha$.  At any rate, uniform in whatever is varying.

Comment: Thank you @NoahSnyder and Autumn Kent :) Now I think I can make some sense out of it.  Do you have some reference where the same exppresion is used as a relation between natural numbers?

Comment: "Approximately equal" is never a phrase that would be used for individual specific natural numbers, it's always going to be used in reference to some kind of function.  In this case *one* of the functions is constant, but if they're both constants then they'd be approximately equal no matter how far apart those constants are.